# Ext.grid.Panel doesn't update when I add a record to the Ext.data.Store it is liked to

Tags: extjs

I have an `Ext.grid.Panel` linked to a `Ext.date.Store`. The panel is inside an `Ext.Window`. If I add a record `{text: 'foo'}` to the store I see that a new row is added to the panel, but it's empty. Then if I close the window and reopen it I can see the previously added row is correctly filled with the 'foo' value.
This means that the record has been added to the store successfully but the panel hasn't refreshed until I reopened the window. The I tried to add

```
myPanel.getView().refresh()
```

right after

```
myStore.add({text: 'foo'})
```

but it's been unusefull. I still need to reopen the window to see my 'foo' string

Comment: Please provide some code with your grid and store declarations

Answer (score -1):

I just replaced

```
myStore.add({text: 'foo'})
```

with

```
myStore.add({field1: 'foo'})
```

The refresh was unnecessary.